# How to exclude the default discord role in a for loop?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using a `for`-loop to go over roles in `ctx.guild.roles` and compare this with a database entry. However, my bot is not excluding the `everyone` role, which causes some problems. Any hints on how I can ignore the `@everyone` role and get all the other roles?

**My code so far/what I tried:**

```py
if role != ctx.guild.default_role:
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        print(role)
```

However this also prints the `@everyone` role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@everyone` is always the first role and `ctx.guild.roles` returns a `list`, so you can just start with the second role:

```py
for role in ctx.guild.roles[1:]:
    print(role)
```

[Read more about list indexes.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_access.asp)